# How to show multiple tables in crystal report using loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I have 2 tables in database `Catagory` and `Product`

```
Catagory...
Id=1 ,CateName="Mobile"
Id=2 ,CateName="Laptop"
Product...
Id=1 ,ProName="Apple" ,CateId=1
Id=2 ,ProName="Android",CateId=1
Id=3 ,ProName="Core I3",CateId=2
```

I just want a to show Catagory wise data in table in crystal report. I use this code. I know this is wrong. This code show all product in one table. I want catagory wise data in tables

```
var li = db.product.ToList();
ReportCompleteChatha rpt = new ReportCompleteChatha();
rpt.Load("~/Reports/ReportCompleteChatha.rpt");
rpt.SetDataSource(li);
collectionreport.ViewerCore.ReportSource = rpt;
```

Comment: What do you mean by _catagory wise data_?

Comment: i mean i want to show All "Mobile" Record in one table and than All "Laptop" Record in 2nd Table using loop and so on

Comment: The you would need to group the data by `CateId` and create a table for each group

Comment: Sir! please give me practicle example by code?

Comment: var li = db.product.GroupBy(x => x.CateId).ToList();

Comment: and now how to use this ....rpt.SetDataSource(li);